# to-infinitive to-infinitive

Tags: grammar

1. I want to get married./
   I wanna get married.

   If Americans think of 'to get married' as an object, which means it's a noun 
   phrase, then why does the phenomenon contracting 'want to' into 'wanna' 
   happen?
2. I advised him not to smoke./
   I advised the reformation of the rules in our company.

   Why do Americans think of 'not to smoke' as an object complement when 'advise' 
   has a direct object?
   Why don't they see it as a 'v+o+o' structure?

Comment: "Wanna* is essentially just an abbreviation of "want to" that is easier to say because it doesn't have the repeated "t" of "want to". I wanna sing, I wanna dance, I wanna do anything; all connecting the "to" of "to [verb]" with "want".

Comment: "If Americans think of 'to get married' as an object" grossly misrepresents a certain  grammatical analysis as being the only one espoused in America.

Comment: Then what's the other analysis, sir?

Comment: This is like asking "If Americans have seven legs, then why does Neil deGrasse Tyson only have two?" Americans do *not* have seven legs, and you yourself have just supplied evidence that they don't.

Comment: Before I got to know that the usage of the first question  is as an object on google or in korean textbooks, I thought the 'get' was some kind of a subordinate verb, not connects with 'to' to make a noun phrase. I thought the 'to' was a word that connects the main verb and the subordinate verb, while the subordinate verb's action or state was what the main verb intends. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Pleeza doncha be ridin *wanna*.

Comment: I think: even if you say "wanna" you should write "want to".  Then you will not be confused by this.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to make sure whether " 'to get merried' is an object" is the only analysis or not, since your mentions are different.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a simple contraction in spoken English. “Wanna” = “want to” ... pretty common.
2. “I advised him not to smoke.” You’re right, “to smoke” is the direct object... “him” serves as the indirect object.